# Query for device name shown in "device and printers" menu

Tags: c#, windows-10

How does one query for the name of device shown in "Devices and printers" menu in settings without admin privaledges?

It is not the friendly name of the device as i first thought it would be, so WMI/ManagementObjectSearcher is not helpful as it does not simple contain this information at all anywhere.(or im unable to find)

Only place i've found this information is in registry under "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\DeviceMigration\Devices\USB\VID_0403&PID_6001\XXXX**BusDeviceDesc**" which would be fine as i could then see which Comports are active and if its the same port found in there, i assume its the one i'm looking for, but the gotcha here is that it does need admin privaledges to dig into registry which is something i would like to avoid.

So is there a way of identifying USB device i'm looking for without admin privaledges, without me buing custom vid/pid from FTDI which would obviously make it easy, but cost quite alot money for hobby project.

**i cannot add pictures to make it more clear

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine;
        key = key.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\DeviceMigration\Devices\USB\VID_0403&PID_6001", true);

ManagementObjectSearcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity where DeviceID Like ""USB%"""))
```

That is how i currently look for the information, then crosscheck the results to identify the device i want connect into, but that needs admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

So after some research i did find a way to do what i want, i post the code here because it might help someone in future.(Sadly this implementation only helps if using FTDI IC)

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        string DeviceActualName = "Fan Control";


        FTDI usbDev = new FTDI();
        UInt32 devCount = 0;
        usbDev.GetNumberOfDevices(ref devCount);
        FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[] infoNode = new FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[devCount];

        string SerialNumber = null;
        usbDev.GetDeviceList(infoNode);
        foreach(FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE node in infoNode) {
            if(node != null && node.Description.Equals(DeviceActualName)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Found: {0} // {1}", node.Description, node.SerialNumber);
                SerialNumber = node.SerialNumber;
            }
        }

        var usbDevices = GetUSBDevices();
        foreach(var usbDevice in usbDevices) {
            if(usbDevice.Name != null)
                if(usbDevice.Name.Contains("COM") && usbDevice.PnpDeviceID.Contains(SerialNumber)) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Match Found:  {0} // {1}", usbDevice.Name, usbDevice.PnpDeviceID);
                    Console.WriteLine("ComPort: {0}", usbDevice.Name[(usbDevice.Name.IndexOf("COM") + 3)]);
                }
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    static List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices() {
        List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

        ManagementObjectCollection collection;
        using(var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity"))
            collection = searcher.Get();

        foreach(var device in collection) {
            devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
            (string) device.GetPropertyValue("Name"),
            (string) device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID")
            ));
        }

        collection.Dispose();
        return devices;
    }
    class USBDeviceInfo {
        public USBDeviceInfo(string Name, string pnpDeviceID) {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.PnpDeviceID = pnpDeviceID;
        }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string PnpDeviceID { get; private set; }
    }
}
```